# How do I join 3 tables that generates this result?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

```
   Users             Requests           Orders
+-----------+     +-------------+     +---------+
| UserId    |<--->| RequesterId |<--->| BuyerId |
+-----------+     +-------------+     +---------+
| FirstName |     | RequestId   |
+ ----------+     +-------------+
| LastName  |
+-----------+
```

I am trying to generate a result that shows the names of both Requester and Buyer in a single query.

The result I want to achieve is:

```
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|RequestId|Requester FirstName|Requester LastName|Buyer FirstName|Buyer LastName|
+---------+-------------------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Here is my failed query:

```
SELECT

 R.RequestID as 'Order #'
,U.FirstName as 'Requester First Name'
,U.LastName as 'Requester Last Name'
,U.FirstName as 'Buyer First Name'
,U.LastName as 'Buyer Last Name'

FROM Requests R

INNER JOIN Users U
ON R.RequesterId = U.UserId

INNER JOIN Orders O
ON U.UserId = O.BuyerID
```

Obviously I'm doing this completely wrong, but I don't know what it is.  Can someone please give me a hint?

Thanks!!

Comment: The results show the same First and Last Name for both the Requester and Buyer.  The Requester should never be the same as the Buyer.

Comment: There needs to be a value that joins `Requests` and `Orders` together.  What is a value that matches on those two tables?  Does the `Orders` table have a field for `RequestId`?

Comment: you are joining the buyer incorrectly. It's being joined on the same user as the requester is joined.

Comment: does the order table have a requesterID?

Comment: If there's nothing that join `Requests` and `Orders`, then you can't link the 2 tables.

Comment: No, the Orders table does not have a field for RequestId.  But it can be joined to the Requests table via another table.  Is that the solution?

Comment: yes, that would be the solution and once you have the order table joined on that other table, you will join the users table again with a new alias name to the buyer id

Answer (score 1):

You will need to treat Users as two separate tables and call one one U1 and the other U2.  So your original select calls would be

```
U1.FirstName as 'Requester First Name'
,U1.LastName as 'Requester Last Name'
,U2.FirstName as 'Buyer First Name'
,U2.LastName as 'Buyer Last Name'
```

Edit: I haven't tested this so don't know if it works, but give it a try:

```
SELECT

 R.RequestID as 'Order #'
,U1.FirstName as 'Requester First Name'
,U1.LastName as 'Requester Last Name'
,U2.FirstName as 'Buyer First Name'
,U2.LastName as 'Buyer Last Name'

FROM Requests R

INNER JOIN Users U1
ON R.RequesterId = U1.UserId

INNER JOIN Orders O
ON R.RequesterId = O.BuyerID

INNER JOIN Users U2
ON O.BuyerID = U2.UserId
```

Edit again: Now that I read some of the comments, I don't think my code will work because I don't think I understand the difference between BuyerID and RequesterID in your tables.  I think you will need a separate field in the Orders table to link to the Requester table, then change my code above by changing

```
ON R.RequesterId = O.BuyerID
```

to

```
ON R.RequesterId = O.RequesterID
```

Comment: And, of course, when you inner join the tables, you will name the user table two different ways.

Comment: So...what's the point of having 2 `Users` tables in this case???  You are joining `r.RequesterId = o.BuyerId`.  They will always be the same person.

Comment: If the requester and the buyer are the same person, then why would they have different names in the search results?  The orders table needs to be changed to include the id of both the buyer and requester

Comment: Either way, the real problem is that the ERD doesn't have any way to link the buyer to the requester, so that needs to be fixed first.

Comment: Thanks for your input PirateJohn, but unfortunately it didn't work. =(